# Paste from Office plugin not stripping font color

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

The PasteFromOffice plugin provided by CK states the following:

```
With CKEditor 5 you do not need to worry about pasting messy content from Microsoft Word (or any other possible sources). 
Thanks to the CKEditor 5 {@link framework/guides/overview custom data model}, only content which is specifically handled by 
the loaded rich-text editor features will be preserved.

This means that if you did not enable, for instance, font font family and font size features, 
this sort of formatting will be automatically stripped off when you paste content from
Microsoft Word and other sources (e.g. other websites).
```

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/pasting/paste-from-word.html

I do not currently have the FontColor enabled in my toolbar, but they are not being automatically stripped out. Other font elements like highlighting is removed as expected, but not color.

Anyone have insights on this?

These are my built in plugins (this is a custom build):

```
ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    Alignment,
    Essentials,
    UploadAdapter,
    Autoformat,
    Bold,
    Italic,
    BlockQuote,
    CKFinder,
    EasyImage,
    Font,
    Heading,
    HorizontalLine, 
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageLinkable, // Homemade
    ImageLinkTarget,
    ImageShareable, // Homemade
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Link,
    List,
    MediaEmbed,
    MediaBrowser, // Homemade
    Mention,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    RemoveFormat,
    SimpleBox, // Homemade
    TweetQuote // Homemade
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because I was importing the entire Font library, it automatically includes FontColor among the other nested plugins. I had incorrectly assumed that the items I added to the toolbar were the included plugins.

To fix my issue I changed my imports from:

```
import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';
```

to

```
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize';
```

Now when I paste in colored text from Word, the color is stripped as expected.